# TimeZone ID coming incorrectly daylight time

Tags: java, timezone

Can anyone please explain this?

```
TimeZone tz1 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(“CST”); ==> ID of tz1 is CST
TimeZone tz2 = TimeZone.getTimeZone(“CDT”); ==> ID of tz2 is GMT ????
```

Comment: From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html): For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported. However, their use is deprecated because the same abbreviation is often used for multiple time zones (for example, "CST" could be U.S. "Central Standard Time" and "China Standard Time"), and the Java platform can then only recognize one of them.

Comment: +1 to anycard's comment.  You should be using full time zone identifiers.  Central time is `America/Chicago`.  It includes both CST and CDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me following test code produces "Not found => CDT":

```
for (String tz : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()) {
    if (tz.equals("CDT")) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + tz);
    }
}

System.out.println("Not found => CDT");
```

That means `java.util.TimeZone` will fall back from non-existing CDT zone to "GMT" as [documented](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone-java.lang.String-):

> Returns: the specified TimeZone, or the GMT zone if the given ID
>   cannot be understood.

In Java 8 you have the alternative of [ZoneId](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-) which has not the unintuitive fallback behaviour but instead throwing a `ZoneRulesException` which I consider to be much better.

Comment: Why must we get a ZoneRulesException at all?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Not throwing an exception means silently falling back to ANY timezone (here GMT) is just guess work and has nothing to do with what a user might expect. And usually the standard timezone of the user on its client machine is NOT GMT so the fallback zone GMT will usually cause wrong timezone calculations which is worse. The exception will at least warn the user to check his program code or input (here CDT) or his zone configuration.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

`CST` & `CDT` are *not* time zones.

Use a real time zone such as [`America/Chicago`](https://time.is/Chicago).

```
ZoneId
.of( "America/Chicago" ) 
.getRules()
.isDaylightSavings( 
    Instant.now()
)
```

> false

## Pseudo-time-zones

> TimeZone.getTimeZone(“CST”)

Whoops, that line makes no sense. `CST` is not a time zone.

Never use the 2-4 letter pseudo-time-zones such as `PST`, `PDT`, `CST`, `IST`, and so on. These are not real time zones. These are not standardized. These are not even unique! For example, I surmise you think of `CST` as “Central Standard Time”. But `CST` is also “China Standard Time”.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
```

## `ZoneId`

Dig to discover the real time zone used by the region in which you are interested. If by `CST` you meant one of the time zones in the midwest of North America, perhaps you really mean something like `America/Chicago` or `America/Winnipeg`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" ) ;
```

The `America/Chicago` time zone participates in the silliness known as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). So we can ask if DST is currently engaged or not. This status of DST being currently in use or not is what is meant when the media publishes `CST` or `CDT`.

### `ZoneRules`

Get the rules for that time zone.

```
ZoneRules rules = z.getRules() ;
```

### `Instant`

Interrogate the status of DST and the offset at a specific moment. We will use the current moment here.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

> now.toString(): 2020-02-10T00:06:26.000116Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

Look at that same moment as seen in our time zone.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = now.atZone( z ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2020-02-09T18:06:26.000116-06:00[America/Chicago]

Now ask about offset and DST.

```
ZoneOffset offset = rules.getOffset( now );
boolean inDST = rules.isDaylightSavings( now );
```

> offset.toString(): -06:00
>
> inDST: false

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/JFoMY5).

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]